# Hadoop CDH4 Error:SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder"

Tags: java, ubuntu, cloudera

I am using ubuntu 14.04. CDH4.7 
I am installing as per the procedure given in the link below 
http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CDH4/latest/CDH4-Quick-Start/cdh4qs_topic_3_2.html
The problem is I am not able to start the data node . I am getting the error as

```
naveensrikanthd@ubuntu:/$ for x in `cd /etc/init.d ; ls hadoop-hdfs-*` ; do sudo service $x start ; done
[sudo] password for naveensrikanthd: 
 * Starting Hadoop datanode: 
starting datanode, logging to /var/log/hadoop-hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-datanode-ubuntu.out
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
 * Starting Hadoop namenode: 
namenode running as process 15437. Stop it first.
 * Starting Hadoop secondarynamenode: 
secondarynamenode running as process 3061. Stop it first.
naveensrikanthd@ubuntu:/$ jps
7467 RunJar
8048 RunJar
18363 Jps
```

No Hadoop process is running and this three statements given above[slf4J] are shuffling between namenode,datanode:

Below given is the log file for the path:
/var/log/hadoop-hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-datanode-ubuntu.out
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
ulimit -a for user hdfs

What should I do to rid of this error anyone please help in crossing this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output shows that in fact the namenodes are already running. You should double-check where you think they are supposed to run and what your config says, because it's saying you already succeeded.

The error from log4j has nothing to do with Hadoop functionality.